# Can't access trollop::options hash by keys?

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to parse the command line with the ruby library Trollop.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'net/http'
require 'trollop'

opts = Trollop::options do
  opt :src, "src lang", :short => 'i', :type => String
  opt :dest, "dest lang", :short => 'o', :type => String
end

opts.each do |key,val|
  puts "#{key}: #{val}"
end

print opts["src"]
print opts["dest"]
```

This is the output:

```
$ ./translate.rb --src he --dest th  
dest_given: true
src: he
dest: th
help: false
src_given: true
nilnil
```

When printing out the hash with `opts.each`, I can see there are keys named `src` and `dest`, and their values are what I expect. However, why accessing the hash values with `opts["src"]` return null?

Comment: Maybe the hash key is a Symbol? Try opts[:src]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[zetetic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17410/zetetic) is correct, the key is a symbol.

And in fact `Enumerable#each` did yield a symbol to your block, but when printing it via `#{...}`, Ruby calls `to_s`, which is defined for symbol and it returns the plain name.

You can tell that Ruby is called `to_s` for string interpolation with a one liner test:

```
>> "ok, #{class A; def to_s; "what fun"; end; self; end.new}, done"
=> "ok, what fun, done"
```